# How do you express this in regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want my condition to return true when it found the **nearest**(from left) **#include** that is preceeded by 
\s***~~**\s*(none or number of whitespaces before or after the ~~).

This should be true:

```
<stdio.h>~~#include<iostream.h> #include<conio.h> int main() { return 0; }

<stdio.h>     ~~#include<iostream.h> #include<conio.h> int main() { return 0; }

<stdio.h>~~  #include    <iostream.h> #include<conio.h> int main() { return 0; }
```

Therefore this should not pass the condition:

```
<stdio.h>~~abc#include<iostream.h> #include<conio.h> int main() { return 0; }
```

I dont know about the first occurence in regexp, all i got is this one:

```
 / *~~\s*#include*/
```

Comment: What regex did you try already? Why _exactly_ didn't it work as you expected? What happened instead?

Comment: @alexWayne  / *~~\s*#include*/

Comment: @fireflieslive Should `<stdio.h>abc~~#include<iostream.h> #include<conio.h> int main() { return 0; }` match? Do the string always begin with `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: @alexWayne: 1. it should match. It simply looks for the existence ~~ before the first occurence of #include.

Comment: @alexWayne: 2. It doesnt always begin with <stdio.h>

Comment: @fireflieslive I'm not alexWayne xD But okay, have you tried alsotang's answer? It could be made shorter though, to `~~\s*#include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/~~\s*?#include\s*?<.*?>/g
```

Is this ok?

[image]

Comment: I think your regex will accept `<stdio.h>abc~~#include<iostream.h> #include<conio.h> int main() { return 0; }` as well, which I don't think the OP intends to match. Additionally, posting answers to questions without any attempt from OP is discouraged.